# zendesk geckoboard custom widget

Tags: php, json, curl, zendesk, geckoboard

We are making use of Geckoboard.com and Zendesk.

I am in the process of creating a custom widget for Geckoboard to get some info (The top ticket solvers) and list them.

For now, I am just trying to push some dummy/hard-coded info to the widget.

My code is as follows:

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init('https://COMPANY_SUBDOMAIN.zendesk.com/api/v2/views/MY_ZD_VIEW_ID/execute.json');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);                         
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'USER_EMAIL/token:MY_UNIQUE_KEY');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);                         

$values = array(
    "api_key"   =>  "MY_UNIQUE_KEY",
    "data"      =>  array(
        "item"      =>  array(
            "title"     =>  "hello",
            "text"      =>  "Some text here"
        )
    )
); 

$v = json_encode($values);

curl_setopt_array($ch = curl_init(), array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://push.geckoboard.com/v1/send/MY_WIDGET_ID",
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $v,
    )
);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

?>
```

All the data in CAPS is my own info.

The message I get when I  execute the file:

{"message":"The property 'text' is not defined "}

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Sorry I am still relatively new to JSON & CURL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solve this. Working code below:

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init('https://{YOUR ZENDESK SUBDOMAIN}.zendesk.com/api/v2/views/{VIEW ID}/execute.json');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, '{EMAIL}/token:{TOKEN}');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$responseToday = curl_exec($curl);
$resultsToday  = json_decode($responseToday, true);

$values = array(
        "item" => array(
            "type" => 1,
            "text" => "Some text here"
        )
);

$v = json_encode($values);

//Simply print this out for the client to consume
echo $v;

/* We don't need this if we're not pushing the widget
curl_setopt_array($ch = curl_init(), array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://push.geckoboard.com/v1/send/{UNIQUE ID}",
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $v
));
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
*/

?>
```